# Can not save product image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I created a form to add products in the frontend, and I've added products with all attributes, except for product image. When I save, it shows: Image does not exist. Please help me find the problem. Thanks.

My template:

```
<div class="field name-image">
    <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Image') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="file" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('image')?>" name="image title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('image')) ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
 $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

 $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "catalog\product" . DS . $filename;
 $product ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))
            ->addImageToMediaGallery($image, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
 $product->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do code like this.

```
$path = '';

if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') 
{
    try 
    {
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array(‘jpg’,’jpeg’,’gif’,’png’));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

        $path = Mage::getBaseDir(‘media’) . DS . "catalog\product" . DS ;
        $uploader->save($path, $_FILES[‘image’][‘name’] );
     } 
     catch (Exception $e) 
     {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
     }

     $product->save();

     $newpath = $path.$_FILES[‘image’][‘name’];
     $product->addImageToMediaGallery($newpath, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);
     $product->save();
}
```